# How to extend the Request type in Express by declaring and merging the type?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

This is my type declaration file `types/index.d.ts`:

```
declare module 'express-serve-static-core' {
  export interface Request {
    user: User
  }
}
```

While this adds the user property, it makes all my standard router arguments throw a TS error that the arguments implicitly have any type:

```
// the req, res, next have the ts error
router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
```

I can fix this by adding an import to the `index.d.ts` file, but I don't understand why this works or if it is correct:

```
import { Request } from 'express-serve-static-core'

declare module 'express-serve-static-core' {
  export interface Request {
    user: User
  }
}
```

Alternatively, I can also fix it by declaring the Express namespace:

```
declare namespace Express {
  export interface Request {
    user: User
  }
}
```

That also works, but again, I don't know if it's correct. From everything I'm reading, the first option should work. This is my tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["ES2019"],
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "types"]
}
```

Comment: The first googled link https://blog.logrocket.com/extend-express-request-object-typescript/ shows exactly kike we do in out projects.

Comment: This clears the errors from vscode for me, however, it then creates a bunch of compliation errors on save like `TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:`

Comment: Could you update the post with the current `index.d.ts` and these errors?